# Regex Matching the same object multiple times during Filtering in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, match

I have a list of objects `people` and I want to filter them based on `regex`.

```
{ name: 'Alice',
  city: 'London',
  country: 'UK',
  pet: 'dog',
  id: '12345' }
```

After I have `fetched` a list of `people`, I am trying to filter them based on the filters user had selected.

```
const nameString = request.body.name || null;
const cityNameString = req.body.city || null;
const countryNameString = req.body.country || null;
const petNameString = req.body.pet || null;
const idNameString = req.body.id || null;

const peopleFiltered = people.filter(person => {
    if(nameString != null){
      person = person.name.match(new RegExp('^' + nameString, 'i'));
    }
    if(cityNameString != null){
      person = person.city.match(new RegExp('^' + cityNameString, 'i'));
    }
    if(countryNameString != null){
      person = person.country.match(new RegExp('^' + countryNameString, 'i'));
    }
    if(petNameString != null){
      person = person.pet.match(new RegExp('^' + petNameString, 'i'));
    }
    if(idNameString != null){
      person = person.id.match(new RegExp('^' + idNameString, 'i'));
    }
   
    return person;
  })

res.status(200).json(peopleFiltered);
```

So basically if user selects the filter `name` and enters `a`, then it brings up all people starting with `a` or `A`. And that works as expected, now the issue comes when user selects multiple filters for the same query.

So for example if user selects filter `name` and enters a value and then selects a second filter which is for example `pet` and enters a value for that, there is no response, because it is trying to match a person that has already been worked on.

First of all, how can I fix my issue and secondly, is there a better solution structually since this does not look that good.

**EDIT**
What is going wrong. If user has selected 2 filters, lets say `name` and `pet`, it will first do the `match` in the first `if` cycle and then it will try to do the match again with the same `person` but the result of the `match` is `["K"]` or whatever was the first `NameString` which is the thing user entered.

So then it tries to do the `match` again with `person.pet` but since it is not there anymore it raises an error.

Comment: What's the current output? What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're reassigning the `person` after each match and that makes it invalid to check afterwards

A (very) verbose solution would be like this

```
const peopleFiltered = people.filter(person => {
  if(nameString) {
    const match = person.name.match(new RegExp('^' + nameString, 'i'))
    if (match) {
      return true
    }
  }
  if(cityNameString) {
    const match = person.city.match(new RegExp('^' + cityNameString, 'i'));
    if (match) {
      return true
    }
  }
  if(countryNameString) {
    const match = person.country.match(new RegExp('^' + countryNameString, 'i'));
    if (match) {
      return true
    }
  }
  if(petNameString) {
    const match = person.pet.match(new RegExp('^' + petNameString, 'i'));
    if (match) {
      return true
    }
  }
  if(idNameString) {
    const match = person.id.match(new RegExp('^' + idNameString, 'i'));
    if (match) {
      return true
    }
  }
})
```

And then, when you understand what's going on, a more elegant solution can be achieved, like using validator functions and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for example

As a side note I recommend using [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) as you're using, mainly because you don't really need the match result but only the boolean result to see if it checks out or not

Comment: Whats the purpose of "return true" here?

Comment: @kataroty [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) expects a function that returns truthy/falsy in order to filter, in the example case we explicitly say "if this is a match then keep it, if it's not then keep looking for other matches. That's why I didn't suggest returning the match directly, because you'd be stuck with the first check (nameString)